# While loop in for loop - For loop does not go through all items

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a while loop withing a for loop. The for loop iterates through all `vel` values, and the while loop calculates the equivalent `b` value for each `vel` value. It toes so by increasing the value of b until it meets a certain requirement (`len([*filter(lambda x: x < 1, radii)]) > 0`)in a different set of code. When i run the code, it only determined the `b` value for the first item in the `vel` list. How can I fix this?

```
def wtf():
    vel = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
    b = 0.1
    bvalues = [b]
    for i in vel:
        print("for velocity = " +str(i))
        radii = calcCoords(1, b, i)[1]
        while len([*filter(lambda x: x < 1, radii)]) > 0:
            b += 0.01
            radii = calcCoords(1, b, i)[1]
            print (b)
        return(b)
        bvalues.append(b)
    print(bvalues, vel)
    return (bvalues, vel)
```

Comment: `return(b)` returns from the function.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! If i remove that does that get me my desired results?

Comment: I have no idea what your desired result is. However, at the least, it will keep looping through all elements of `vel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unconditional return in the body of the for-loop.

```
def wtf():
    vel = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
    b = 0.1
    bvalues = [b]
    for i in vel:
        print("for velocity = " +str(i))
        radii = calcCoords(1, b, i)[1]
        while len([*filter(lambda x: x < 1, radii)]) > 0:
            b += 0.01
            radii = calcCoords(1, b, i)[1]
            print (b)
        return(b)  # <- This is why the for loop runs only once
        bvalues.append(b)
    print(bvalues, vel)
    return (bvalues, vel)
```

As soon as the while loop runs once, it hits the `return` & the rest of the `for` iterations are not run - your function returns.

Comment: Sorry that was a fairly basic mistake, but this is super helpful thanks!!! So if I remove that will I get a list of b, with each item in the list being the b value equivalent to the vel list?